# Identify these wide ended tweezers

Tags: identification, pcb-assembly, tools

Working in an electronics lab, we do micro soldering and I came across the tool pictured. No Idea what it's is for. I'm guessing its some tool for holding or removing chips as you rework a PCB. I don't even know what to call it (forked flat plate tweezers?) so looking around got me a lot of cosmetic tweezers and normal component handling but I can't seem to find this shape.

Can anyone help?

It's not a major issue just a nice to know if someone else knows.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looks like some [wafer tweezer](https://www.ideal-tek.com/scheda.php?m=0&f=8&c=Wafer%20Tweezers&l=3&idp=925)

These tweezers are especially designed for the handling of delicate and fragile silicon wafers, scintillation discs, glass slides, coverslips etc.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I was working at a TI fab in production and this tool was used there very often

Comment: +1, I also use these often. It would be worth mentioning how they're used. Namely that the flat of a wafer is aligned with the recessed portion of the tip of the tweezers.